# How to set AssemblyInfo.cs based on the tfs project build number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

The project is hosted on a tfs server and I need to access the build number which I assume is automatically generated when ever you build a project.

I need to retrieve that build number and display it on the web pages so that QAs and testing people know exactly which build they are working on.

I found how to create customize build numbers in the following link:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395241(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395241%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

but it dose not solve my problem as I do not have access to the build definition file.

I am looking  for some kind of post deployment task which can access the build number or may be generate one and probably write it down to a file, from where I can read it. I don't know if that makes any sense as this is my first time working on .Net

Comment: You need to set the assembly file version in AssemblyInfo.cs based on the build number

Comment: Hi John, I tried setting  "[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
and [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")] " but it still didn't auto update my build number so then I tired using  "[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.*")]" it did change it to a new value on the first build but then after that it spits the same value no matter how many times I build it. where do you think I am going wrong ?

Comment: You should add an answer showing how you got it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

or alternatively if you have multiple assemblies then you can use

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeObject))
```

where `SomeObject` is declared in the assembly you want to get the version of.

Comment: Hi mclaassen thanks for sharing your knowledge, the approach seems to work but I am not able to make my project spit out a new version value/number for each build as I was explaining to John I tried setting  "[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
and [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")] " but it still didn't auto update my build number so then I tired using  "[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.*")]" it did change it to a new value on the first build but then after that it spits the same value no matter how many times I build it. where do you think I am going wrong ?

Comment: @AhokRudraraju Hmm not sure, I have used the * approach before and it worked for me. Maybe try doing a rebuild and see if that increments it?

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I ended up implementing it Thanks to John and mclaassen.

In my AssemblyInfo.cs, I made the following changes:

before:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

after:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

then I wrote a helper class which can access the AssemblyVersion number, with a get method.

```
public string GetVersion() 
{
    string version ;
    version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    return version;
}
```

so when ever I call this method it gives me a string which is nothing but my version number.

Answer (score 0):

[TFS Versioning](https://tfsversioning.codeplex.com/) is a good extension to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You would do best to use the TFS Version activity from the TFS Community build tools. This tool automatically grabs the version number from the build name and can be easily configured to update the AssemblyInfo.* files after the get, and before the compile.

- https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20TfsVersion%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation

Of all the tools out there this is the best supported one. I find any of the others overly complicated. I have used this on hundreds of builds for many customers.